# python store function in array

Tags: python, arrays, function

N00b question, maybe.

I am new-ish to python, but I was wondering if it is possible to store a function in an array? I want to do an array multiplication, where the value of one array is multiplied by a function on a location of another array of functions. Or actually, the value of the first array is inserted in the function of the designated location. This should create a new array where the values are an outcome of the "multiplication".

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
>>> b = [[f(x), g(x)], [(h(x), f(x)]]
>>> np.dot(a, b)
array([[0, 1],
   [2, 0]])
```

Assuming that f(x), g(x) and h(x) are defined functions. In this case python will say that x is not defined. So far I know. However, I do not want to say, for example, f(a[0][1]), because I want to reuse array b and also be able to put the functions on random locations in the array.

In short I detect three questions: 
 - Is there a known way to have an array where the values are functions?
 - If not, should I redefine an array function or write a new class for this? (how do I attack this problem?)
 - If it is possible to create an array of functions, can I fill the 'function values' dynamically in the array (populate the array dynamically with functions) or can it only be static values?

like for example

```
b[0]=f(x)
```

And yes, I really want to do this with python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f(x)` is not a function (even in mathematics). The function is f. In python there is no problem to store functions in array:

```
def my_func():
    print("Foo")

my_other_func = lambda: print("Bar")

my_arr = [my_func, my_other_func]
```

Comment: f(x) represents a function, but I do not know which function yet. I think your solution might be what I was searching for. Thanks!

Comment: functions are not special in python, every array operation will work normally. Also, unless the result of calling f with x is itself a function, f(x) is not a function

Comment: When I do, say def my_func(x): 6 * x (with proper styling ofcourse) and def my_func(x): 8 * x then it gives me a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'function'

Comment: a = [1, 0]  and then np.dot(a, my_arr)

Comment: That numpy method is not supposed to work on function, only integer or complex numbers. You might want to do a list comprehension to do something like that.

Comment: something like [x*2 for x in range(3)], how would that work with my examples? Could it only work with for loops?

Comment: [ f(x) for f in functions for x in values] where functions is an array of functions and values is an array of values

Comment: So, it can not be done with an my_arr = [my_func, my_other_func] and arr = [1, 0] ?

Comment: Can you try my example with the names changed?

Comment: I tried it, but then I can only use 1 function. How would this work with an array of functions? a for loop in a for loop?

Comment: My list comprehension works for multiple functions, just replace the names in it.

Comment: It does, but then I would not need to put a function as a parameter of an array. I apologise if I do not understand what you mean, but my aim is to have a matrix manipulation situation to avoid for loops. Can you give me an example where I would use my_arr in your list comprehension ?

Comment: [ f(x) for f in my_arr for x in arr]

Comment: I am accepting this as an answer. It comes closest to what I want. Too bad it can not be done without for loops. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your example puts the result of *calling* a function into your array.

```
b[0] = f
```

actually puts the function itself into the array, so that

```
b[0](x)
```

would have the same effect as

```
f(x)
```

Comment: I see. I did not know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Is there a known way to have an array where the values are functions?

There is, as stated by others already.

```
def my func(x):
    return x

my_other_func = lambda x: x

l = [my_func, my_other_func]
```

## If not, should I redefine an array function or write a new class for this? (how do I attack this problem?)

Not relevant

## If it is possible to create an array of functions, can I fill the 'function values' dynamically in the array (populate the array dynamically with functions) or can it only be static values?

The 'function values' are called parameters and can be assigned after having the function in the array:

```
a[0](5)       # == my_func(5)
a[1]('Hello') # == my_other_func('Hello')
```

The problem is that you are trying to use matrix multiplication as parameter passing and that will not work, you could create a helper fucntion that does it.

```
def callByElements(parameterMatrix, functionMatrix):
    rows = len(parameterMatrix)
    cols = len(parameterMatrix[0])
    result = np.zeros( (rows, cols) )
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            result[i,j] = functionMatrix[i,j](parameterMatrix[i,j])
    return result
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I purposely do not want to use for loops and was hoping that it would be possible in a matrix instead. haha, yes I totally could think of the word parameter, thanks.

Comment: Well you cant expect `np.dot()` which is a matrix multiplication method to work as a function calling method.

Comment: Yes I saw that, but it was merely to illustrate my intensions. I want to do matrix manipulations as it is often faster than for loops.